# On select/de-select a cell write/erase a value

Tags: excel, vba, cell, conditional-formatting

I have in Excel 2 ranges: Range("B4:T13"), Range("B17:T26"). In these ranges there are applied 5 conditional formatting settings, each of them make a particular column colored. For example the columns 2,3,6,7,8,13,14,20,21,22,29,30 are colored based on a different condition. I wanted to write a code in VBA:  If i click to select a cell in this range, the letters “SZ” should appear in the cell, if i click the same cell again, the letters “SZ” should vanish. These two different actions should work only on cells, which are not colored with the a conditional formatting settings.
Then I tried to modify: if cells are red, grey and blue, no cell changes are needed, if cells are yellow and green, the two actions should work on them too.
The following code doesn't work at all, it doesn't do anything on the worksheet. What have i done wrong?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim selectedCell As Range
    Dim rangesToCheck As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Define the ranges you want to check
    rangesToCheck = Array(Range("B4:T13"), Range("B17:T26"))

    For i = LBound(rangesToCheck) To UBound(rangesToCheck)
        Set selectedCell = Intersect(Target, rangesToCheck(i))

        If Not selectedCell Is Nothing Then ' Red, Blue, Grey
            If Not HasConditionalFormatting(selectedCell) And _
               Not IsCellColored(selectedCell, RGB(252, 228, 214)) And _
               Not IsCellColored(selectedCell, RGB(189, 215, 238)) And _
               Not IsCellColored(selectedCell, RGB(174, 170, 170)) Then
                                            ' Yellow, Green
                If IsCellColored(selectedCell, RGB(255, 230, 153)) Or _
                   IsCellColored(selectedCell, RGB(198, 224, 180)) Then
                    If selectedCell.Value = "SZ" Then
                        selectedCell.ClearContents
                    Else
                        selectedCell.Value = "SZ"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Function HasConditionalFormatting(rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim formatCondition As formatCondition
    Dim column As Integer

    For Each formatCondition In rng.FormatConditions
        If formatCondition.AppliesTo.Columns.Count = rng.Columns.Count Then
            For column = rng.column To rng.column + rng.Columns.Count - 1
                If formatCondition.AppliesTo.Columns(column) Then
                    HasConditionalFormatting = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next column
        End If
    Next formatCondition
End Function

Function IsCellColored(rng As Range, color As Long) As Boolean
    Dim cellColor As Long
    cellColor = rng.Cells(1, 1).Interior.color
    IsCellColored = (cellColor = color)
End Function
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code?

Answer (score 0):

- Using `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` to get the conditional formatting color
- Using `Set rangesToCheck = Application.Union()` to get merged range
- Adding `If Target.CountLarge > 1` to avoid multiple cells selection

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim selectedCell As Range
    Dim rangesToCheck As Range
    Dim i As Integer, iColor As Long
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    ' Define the ranges you want to check
    Set rangesToCheck = Application.Union(Me.Range("B4:T13"), Me.Range("B17:T26"))
    Set selectedCell = Intersect(Target, rangesToCheck)
    If Not selectedCell Is Nothing Then
        If HasConditionalFormatting(selectedCell) Then
            iColor = selectedCell.Cells(1, 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.color
            ' Yellow, Green
            If iColor = RGB(255, 230, 153) Or iColor = RGB(198, 224, 180) Then
                If selectedCell.Value = "SZ" Then
                    selectedCell.ClearContents
                Else
                    selectedCell.Value = "SZ"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function HasConditionalFormatting(rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim formatCondition As formatCondition
    Dim column As Integer
    For Each formatCondition In rng.FormatConditions
        If formatCondition.AppliesTo.Columns.Count = rng.Columns.Count Then
            For column = rng.column To rng.column + rng.Columns.Count - 1
                If formatCondition.AppliesTo.Columns(column) Then
                    HasConditionalFormatting = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next column
        End If
    Next formatCondition
End Function
```